# Including off-canvas layouts with the zurb-foundation Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

What is the right way of implementing the Foundation's off-canvas layouts in a Rails project?

I am using the zurb-foundation gem, and tried both version 3.x and 4 (with rails generators). The off-canvas js/css files do not seem to get included in my pages. Should I be including these manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never.

I just hade this issue and its due to the fact that the `zurb-foundation` gem is badly out of date.

Remove:

```
gem "zurb-foundation"
```

Run:

```
bundle clean -F
```

Add:

```
gem 'foundation-rails'
```

Run:

```
bundle install
```

And restart your server.